# Mysql USING rename column

Tags: mysql

What i'm trying to do is `sub.blockid=id` with the JOIN.  I've renamed `blockid` as `id` in the subquery but the USING keyword is still attaching the column `id` instead of the renamed `id` column(blockid) from the subscribe table.

```
 $subscribequery = "JOIN (SELECT id as subid, blockid as id from subscribe WHERE userid='1') AS sub
    USING (id)";
```

This would be easy with `ON` but i have other JOIN subqueries with USING.  I get the column is ambigious error if i try to use `ON` instead of `USING` along with the other subqueries.

Can you use both `USING` and `ON` in the same query?  Can i rename the column as i have attempted above?

Here is the full query.  The culprit is the second JOIN query.

```
SELECT * FROM products
JOIN (SELECT nid, sid, name AS max_name from products WHERE guideline='1' group by nid, sid) AS at1
        USING (nid, sid)
JOIN (SELECT id as subid, blockid as id from subscribe WHERE userid='1') AS sub
        USING (id)
WHERE id = subid AND name = max_name AND pending='0' AND deleted='0'
ORDER BY subid DESC, nid DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, you're not really renaming any columns, just aliasing them. And yes, since you are using a sub-query you can use the column alias in the `ON` or `USING` clause int eh outer query.

I recommend you use `ON` instead of `USING`, and simply specify which table or sub-query each column refers to using either the table name or the table alias.

Using `ON` and being explicit about which table you are referring to also makes your code more readable, especially considering that you are using multiple joins.

Here's an example using your query:

```
JOIN (SELECT nid, sid, name AS max_name from products WHERE guideline='1' group by nid, sid) AS at1
        ON at1.nid = products.nid and at1.sid = products.sid
JOIN (SELECT id as subid, blockid as id from subscribe WHERE userid='1') AS sub
        ON sub.id = products.id
```